# Hotkey Shortcut for next typo error in Visual Studio, code window

Tags: visual-studio

F8 is by default the hotkey for jumping to the next compilation error, or to the next find when searching with CTRL-SHIFT-F.

But what's the corresponding key to jump to the next error in the code window? Can't find it anywhere in the hotkey mappings or by googling it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

CTRL+SHIFT+F12 which is View.NextError

Comment: and with Resharper (or maybe Visual Studio too) it's Alt+PgDwn

Comment: What is the shortcut key combo to go to the previous error?